# Printing out ActiveCell value on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a button which on click will print out the value of a cell as a string and not the appearance of the cell itself (if that makes sense) using the `.PrintOut` method in `VBA`. That cell is the active cell, whose value I set based on the cell next to it. Here is my code:

```
Sub Graphic2_Click()
    Dim MyNumber as Integer
    MyNumber = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) + 1
    ActiveCell.Value = MyNumber
    ActiveCell.Printout
End Sub
```

I also tried `MyNumber.PrintOut` but I get an "*Invalid Qualifier*" error.

Am I missing out something too simple?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Range.Printout`

Comment: That gives me an "Argument not optional" compile error :/

Comment: Why the `+1` on the end of he MyNumber line?  That's trying to add one to the value of the activecell.... if it's text it will throw an error.

Comment: What happens when you run the posted code? Seems to work for me. As @DarrenBartrup-Cook notes, you are trying to add 1 to a variable declared a string which makes no sense.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, value of the cell is a number so there's no problem with the code getting the desired value right.

Comment: @SJR the printer prints the cell itself and not its value (with the border and everything). Sorry about declaring as string, but if I declare as integer in the code, I still get the same result

Comment: I don't think you can not print borders etc, a printout is a physical representation of what is on your sheet.

Comment: @SJR I understand, I'm just looking to see whether I can print the *contents* of the cell and not just the cell itself. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

### To literally print just the contents of the cell:

1. Clear number formatting for the specified cell
2. Autofit column width for that column
3. Turn off gridlines
4. Turn off row and column headings
5. Set print area to the single cell, dismissing any warnings
6. Print out the active sheet

Each of these are straightforward to do in VBA, and probably straightforward to research on SO anyway.

You may also consider a mechanism to return the changed settings to their initial states afterwards. This would involve pushing (storing) the initial state to a variable or variables first, and popping (restoring) it back afterwards.

**Explanation:**

The VBA method `.PrintOut` is something you do to a worksheet, not a cell or its contents. Therefore, to get what you need, you need to set up the worksheet for printing so that the only thing that will appear is the contents of your chosen cell. This is what the above steps do.

For more information about the `.PrintOut` method, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.printout

### Or, to continue what the OP tried:

You could try something like:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-1,0)).Value2 + 1
```

If this does not work, try:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-1,0).Address).Value2 + 1
```

Or try these without the `+ 1` on the end, to verify that the rest of the formula is working the way you want it too. As mentioned, you may get a type mismatch issue causing an error if you don't trap first for whether the referenced cell contains a number.

`.Formula` in this example is how I am setting the content of the cell, and it can be used even when setting a value not necessarily literally a formula. You could use `Value` instead if you prefer.

`.Value2` is a robust method of extracting the evaluated content of the source cell, as a value instead of as a formula.

The `PrintOut` method is to print a worksheet, not a range or single cell.

**Note:** This answer is not tested, as I am not near Excel right now.

Also... it's possible that there could be much simpler ways to do what you are trying to accomplish. Could you provide a bit more detail about the context of what you are trying to do.

Comment: `Formula` should only be used when inserting a formula, and using it will not make any difference to the OP's situation.

Comment: Edited answer to clarify.

Comment: Unfortunately still not printing the contents of the cell. I should have been more clear in that the other parts of my code work just fine, the main issue is printing. Thanks a lot for your answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. It use a temporary 'helper cell' where the format to be pasted (and recuperated after printing out):

```
Sub Graphic2_Click()
  Dim helperCell As Range

  With ActiveCell
    .value = CLng(Offset(-1, 0)) + 1
    Set helperCell = .Offset(1) 'it may be any cell to temporarilly be used
    .Copy
    helperCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .ClearFormats
    .PrintOut
    helperCell.Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats: helperCell.ClearFormats
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately still not printing just the number in the active cell, but thanks so much

Comment: But what should it print? This is what I understood you need. Only the format to be missing...

Comment: @Fedra Please, edit your question and show us two pictures. One showin how the cell is printed now and a second one showing what wou want.